# c++ defining a member-function pointer without knowing the type of the object

Tags: c++, pointers

I know that the title is not very clear but I didn't know how to write it down in one sentence. So the problem is that I want something like this:

```
void(typeof(this)::*function)(int,int);
```

I know that is not going to work but I was wandering whether a solution exists for this problem in c++ or not?

Update:

```
class MainPage
{
    public:
    MainPage()
    {
        void (std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::*callback)(int, int) = &MainPage::myFunction;
        ((*this).*callback)(nullptr,nullptr);
    }
    ~MainPage()
    {

    }

    void myFunction(int a, int b)
    {
    }
}
```

Errors:

error C2440: 'newline' : cannot convert from 'MainPage *' to 'std::remove_reference<_Ty> *'

error C2647: '.*' : cannot dereference a 'void (__thiscall std::remove_reference<_Ty>::* )(int,int)' on a 'MainPage'

Comment: If you actually mean `this`, `decltype(*this)::*`.

Comment: Ok I tried it but this line gives error: 
void (decltype(*this)::*callback)(int, int);

Comment: I think you might be interested in the fastdelegate library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use `decltype`:

```
void (std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type::*function)(int, int);
```

Comment: errors:
error C2645: no qualified name for pointer to member (found ':: *')
error C2144: syntax error : 'MainPage &' should be preceded by ')'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: @user2439854, `std::remove_reference` [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d5bfca24ebb028a74c1757c83e8b0dd9-e434afe6909ff0e74aaeafde0a4175f3).

Comment: @chris I was about to suggest that as well.

Comment: Ok with std::remove_reference works fine and I will mark this as an answer thank you very much. Just one more little question. How to call that function because this doesn't work: 
(*this.*function)(1,1);

Comment: @user2439854 Use parenthesis: `((*this).*function)(1,1); ` because `*` has very little precedence.

Comment: @user2439854 Can you post a small example that replicates the issue.

Comment: @user2439854 What error are you getting? My program works fine -- http://ideone.com/JEVKJO

Comment: @user2439854 Oh I see what's happening. I will update my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see the ::type::. Now it works fine. Thank you very much folks you help me a lot.